# How to quickly create dataframe with repeated values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to build a 3,000 row long dataframe with code only (so far I import the document from XLS), following these rules:

Top index: [image]

Flight Number: I would like to define the numbers in another simpler dataframe. The flight numbers stay the same 24 times (see departure times). Dataframe would look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Flight Number':['LX2104','LX2105','LX2320','LX2321','LX1232','LX1232'], 
               'Leg Route': ['GVA-AGP','GVA-AGP','GVA-AJA','GVA-AJA','GVA-ARN','GVA-ARN']})
               'Leg Flight Pair': ['LX2104/2105','LX2104/2105','LX2320/2321','LX2320/2321','LX1232/1233','LX1232/1233']})
```

[image]

**STD Departure:** From - to 23 (-, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)
**Leg Route**: Similar to Flight Number this would also be defined in the dataframe (df above)
**Leg Flight Pair:** Similar to Flight Number & Leg Route, this would also be defined in the dataframe (df above)
**Products:** I would list the product names in a list

This would be the beginning of the expected outcome[image]

Comment: Hello @ManuH. Just to clarify, you want 4 columns, 3 of them will all be the same value apart from STD Departure which will range from 0 to 23?

Comment: Yes, first four columns are most important. 3 of them will be defined in another dataframe, however, I still need them 24 times each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Flight Number':['LX2104','LX2105','LX2320','LX2321','LX1232','LX1232'], 
    'Leg Route': ['GVA-AGP','GVA-AGP','GVA-AJA','GVA-AJA','GVA-ARN','GVA-ARN'],
    'Leg Flight Pair': ['LX2104/2105','LX2104/2105','LX2320/2321','LX2320/2321','LX1232/1233','LX1232/1233']
})
```

```py
n_flights = len(df)
df = pd.concat([df]*24).sort_values('Flight Number').reset_index(drop=True)
df['STD Departure'] = np.tile(np.arange(24), n_flights)
```

```py
cols = ['Prod1', 'Prod2']
for col in cols:
  df[col] = 0
```

**Output**

```
>>> df.head()

Flight Number   Leg Flight Pair     Leg Route   STD Departure   Prod1   Prod2
0   LX1232      LX1232/1233         GVA-ARN             0           0       0
1   LX1232      LX1232/1233         GVA-ARN             1           0       0
2   LX1232      LX1232/1233         GVA-ARN             2           0       0
3   LX1232      LX1232/1233         GVA-ARN             3           0       0
4   LX1232      LX1232/1233         GVA-ARN             4           0       0
```

Comment: (Sorry for the delay) It worked! Thank you very much. Is there a way that I can add the product column headers from a dictionary or another dataframe? This way I don't have to always change it in the script but can change the dictionary/dataframe